# How to avoid over-taxing a server in repeated calls to an API from R

Tags: api, r, curl

I have an R function which calls a webserver database through it's API using the RCurl library and getURLContent() function.  I often loop over repeated calls to getURLContent(), which can be taxing to the server.  Is there anything I can pass through the R/curl interface to avoid being too demanding on the server?

Here's an example, where url[i] is the i'th url address in a vector corresponding to different queries to some API.

```
curl = getCurlHandle()
sapply(url, function(u) getURLContent(u, curl=curl))
```

Comment: I suppose the most trivial thing would be to add a pause into the sapply statement.  I'm wondering if there's anything more sensible than this?

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the code on the webserver? E.g., could you modify the server-side code to do the work of all of the URLs wrapped into a single PHP URL taking multiple arguments?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the webserver is run by an external service which provides the API.  I just access the API through R.  Best I have so far is adding a Sys.sleep(.1) into the sapply function loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ``generic'' suggestion I have would be to ensure that curl keeps the connection to the server alive between requests. This feature of the HTTP protocol is called keep-alive. I read that some curl implementations do this by default. But I don't know which version you are using. This will not reduce the load on the server which is generated by PHP, it will however reduce the overhead associated with each request and could therefore also speed up your R code.

Comment: Thanks - but I believe am already doing this (I think) by passing the value of getCurlHandle.  I agree that making repeated calls to getURLContent without passing the curl option would involve even more overhead, since each call would invoke a new call to getCurlHandle. (I've run out of local memory by forgetting that).  Unless I misunderstood the role of that option?

Comment: getCurlHandle helps keep this alive.  My primary memory problem came from a version of RCurl that I understand wasn't running garbage collection correctly.  The latest version of RCurl has improved performance dramatically.